# Present small ModalVIewController ObjectiveC

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, modalviewcontroller

My task is adding new simple notification modal view in some existing VC's.
At best, I want to implement a function that shows notificationVC over current view.

There are a lot of similar questions, but they are not working for me or needs delegates, segues, etc.

Thanks, this is like what I want:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to present a view controller over another view controller, it is easiest to set the `modalPresentationStyle` to either `UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen` or `UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext`. If the presented view controller's view has a background color with alpha less than one the presenting view controller's view will show through. Using your example, in your presenting view controller you can say something like:

```
- (void) presentNotificationViewController
{
    NotificationViewController *notificationVC = [[NotificationViewController alloc] init];
    notificationVC.titleText = @"My Notification Title";
    notificationVC.image = image;
    notificationVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen;
    notificationVC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentViewController:notificationVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Then your `NotificationViewController.m` can be something like:

```
#import "NotificationViewController.h"

@interface NotificationViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *contentView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *notificationTitleLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *dismissButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;

@end

@implementation NotificationViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.60];

    self.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0;

    self.notificationTitleLabel.text = self.titleText;

    self.imageView.image = self.image;

    self.dismissButton.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0;
    self.dismissButton.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    self.dismissButton.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
    // etc.

}


- (IBAction)dismissPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

@end
```

Or whatever you want. Notice, I set the background color of the view to be semi transparent while I have a contentView that is opaque-white that acts as the actual alert view. `contentView` has a label, button, and image view as subviews. This code along with the .xib where I set up my UI with constraints, results in:

[image]

Comment: I tried code like this, but I'm getting fullscreen notificationVC. idk what's wrong, maybe i missed anything in NotificationVC.xib

Comment: That's correct this should show a fullscreen ViewController, however the main view is semi transparent, so you can see the view behind, the image view in the middle isn't transparent and therefore you get the desired effect. Does that make sense? I'm happy to try clarify further if necessary.